# RSpec/Capybara check not triggering onChange event

Tags: javascript, rspec, webkit, capybara, onchange

I'm testing my `JavaScript` with `RSpec` and `Capybara` with `Webkit driver`. 
After I `check` a checkbox, JS `onChange` event validates the form and  disables `submit` button untill I check second checkbox.

Here's my test:

```
it "disables submit button when wrong number of players", js: true do
  visit '/matches/new'
  check 'match_player_ids_1'
  expect(page).to have_button('Create Match', disabled: true)
end
```

I tried using `sleep 2` after checking the checkbox, used `binding.pry` to check if the element is being checked (it is) but the submit button is still disabled.

Any ideas?  Can it be triggered manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually do it with page.execute_script

```
page.execute_script("$('#match_player_ids_1').trigger('change')")
```